# How to perform an action on MaterialDatePicker in an Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a `MaterialDatePicker` dialog, and I want to write an Espresso test that selects a date. Unfortunately, I can't use `PickerActions` for this. I'm looking for something similar to this:

```kotlin
onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(DatePicker.class.getName()))).perform(PickerActions.setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set time to MaterialDateTimePicker with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658871/how-to-set-time-to-materialdatetimepicker-with-espresso)

Comment: No, it's a different Android component, and they work quite differently.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66200995/4560689) buried in the question linked above, which you may find useful for setting the date when the InputMode is `INPUT_MODE_TEXT`.

```
public static void setDate(LocalDate date){
    onView(withTagValue((Matchers.is((Object) ("TOGGLE_BUTTON_TAG"))))).perform(click());
    onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.mtrl_picker_text_input_date)).perform(replaceText(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy"))));
}

public static void setTime(LocalTime time){
    onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.material_timepicker_mode_button)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.material_hour_text_input)).perform(click());
    onView(allOf(isDisplayed(), withClassName(is(AppCompatEditText.class.getName())))).perform(replaceText(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh"))));
    onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.material_minute_text_input)).perform(click());
    onView(allOf(isDisplayed(), withClassName(is(AppCompatEditText.class.getName())))).perform(replaceText(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm"))));
}
```

It's definitely janky in terms of relying very closely on the ids to not change, but it is effective.

If you want to select a date when the InputMode is `INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR`, then this worked for me:

```
onView(
   // the date you are selecting must be visible for this to work 
   withContentDescription("Mon, Jan 1, 1990")
).inRoot(RootMatchers.isDialog())
  .perform(click())

onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.confirm_button))
  .perform(click())
```

You could expand this answer further to select a different month/day/year by clicking on the appropriate buttons in the Material Date Picker layout. You can go spelunking for the ids in the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/res/layout).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add @Chantell Osejo's comment. Some dates will have different content description like these:

```
"Mon, Jan 1, 2024"
"Fri, Dec 29"
"Today Thu, Dec 28"
```

And if you're using `MaterialDatePicker.dateRangePicker()`, when you've selected the start date, the content description of the selected start date will be e.g. `"Start date Mon, Jan 1, 2024"`.

Here is the Matcher I've made based on @Chantell Osejo's comment. Still need some improvement, feel free to comment.

```
fun withDate(date: Date): Matcher<View> {
    fun areDatesEqual(calendar1: Calendar, calendar2: Calendar): Boolean {
        return calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH) &&
                calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    }

    fun areYearsEqual(calendar1: Calendar, calendar2: Calendar): Boolean {
        return calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    }
    val now = Calendar.getInstance()
    val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        time = date
    }

    val isToday = areDatesEqual(now, selectedDate)
    val areYearsEqual = areYearsEqual(now, selectedDate)

    val dateFormat = if (areYearsEqual) {
        SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d")
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy")
    }

    val finalDate = if (isToday) {
        "Today ${dateFormat.format(date)}"
    } else {
        dateFormat.format(date)
    }

    return withContentDescription(finalDate)
}
```

Usage:

```
val tomorrowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
}
onView(withDate(tomorrowCalendar.time))
    .inRoot(RootMatchers.isDialog())
    .perform(click())
onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.confirm_button))
    .perform(click())
```